# ManyToMany querying django

Tags: django

I have:

```
Foo <=> FooGroup <=> Bar
```

relation, where `<=>` stands for `ManyToManyField`.

How do I retrieve all the `Foo`s for a specific `Bar` instance?

Comment: Why not share the Django models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Foo.objects.filter(foogroup__bar=mybar)
```

with *`mybar`* the `Bar` object for which you want to retrieve the `Foo`s. It is possible that `Foo` is linked to the same `Bar` through *multiple* `FooGroup`s, then it will occur *multiple* times in the queryset as well. You can use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(foogroup__bar=mybar).distinct()
```